# Onclick function does nothing in image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, image-gallery

I'm learning to make image gallery and when i click on thumbnail, it does nothing. Bellow is my code, I'm trying for some tome to make it work, can I get some help ?
HTML :

```
        <script src="galerijaSlika.js"></script>
        <img id="glavnaSlika" src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info1.jpg">
        <div id="sveSlike" onClick="promjeniSliku(event)">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info1.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info2.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info3.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info4.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info5.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info6.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info7.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info8.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info9.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info10.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info11.jpg">
            <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info12.jpg">
        </div>
```

Javascript :

```
function promjeniSliku(event){
     event = event || window.event;
     var trazeniElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
     if(trazeniElement == "IMG"){
          document.getElementById("glavnaSlika").src = trazeniElement.getAttribute("src");

     }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `event` is null or undefined, in which case `trazeniElement != "IMG"`?  Do you get errors in your browser console?

Comment: @Marc when I remove if, it works, but if I click between pictures, there is not showing any picture, but it shows broken picture logo. And I don't get any error in console.

Comment: Change puppies to kittens and back: https://jsfiddle.net/hsLebj5g/ (Fixes onClick assignment via jQuery and checks tagName and nodeName for case-insensitive match to 'img')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your typo is:

```
if(trazeniElement == "IMG"){
```

The correct test must be:

```
if (trazeniElement.tagName == "IMG") {
```

For details see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)

```js
function promjeniSliku(event){
  event = event || window.event;
  var trazeniElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
  if (trazeniElement.tagName == "IMG") {
    document.getElementById("glavnaSlika").src = trazeniElement.getAttribute("src");
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="glavnaSlika" src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info1.jpg">
<div id="sveSlike" onClick="promjeniSliku(event)">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info1.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info2.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info3.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info4.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info5.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info6.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info7.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info8.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info9.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info10.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info11.jpg">
    <img src="Slike/infogamer_galerija/info12.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. I had to change the images around, and to get a larger item in the galeria image I had to do a string replace, feel free to delete that part.

```js
function promjeniSliku(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName == 'IMG') {

    var src = target.src.replace(/100/g, '500');
    document.getElementById('glavnaSlika').src = src;
  }

}
```

```html
<img id="glavnaSlika" src="//lorempixel.com/500/500/cats/1">
<div id="sveSlike" onclick="promjeniSliku(event)">
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/1" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/2" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/3" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/4" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/5" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/6" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/7" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/8" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/9" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/10" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/11" alt="" />
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/12" alt="" />

</div>
```